Bathymetry rasters
I have 2 bathymetry rasters of same shape but different min/max values.I need to create a new ratser of same shape that show depth difference between these 2.

Use the Raster Calculator tool in QGIS to create a simple difference raster by using the formula raster1 - raster2. The resulting output raster will show the differences in depth between the two.

You could improve this answer with some more detail showing the asker how to use the raster calculator.

And the formula would be "Raster1@1" - "Raster2@1" (i.e "layer name@band number")
